# How to priortize based on range/filter of Elastic Search DSL, such that a list can be filtered, first to show with availability > 60% first and then <

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest, elasticsearch.net

The relevance of the Applicants needs to sort, based on availability % in the month.
First, the applicants with %availabiliity more than 60% should come and then the applicants with %availability less than 60% should come.

The Fluent DSL query using ElasticSearch.net which I am trying with

```
var response = await 
_elasticClient.SearchAsync<ApplicantsWithDetailsResponse>(s =>
                             s.Aggregations(a => a

.Filter("higer_average", f => f.Filter(fd => fd.Range(r => r.Field(p 
=> p.AvailablePercentage).GreaterThanOrEquals(60).Boost(5))))

.Filter("lower_average", f => f.Filter(fd => fd.Range(r => r.Field(p 
=> p.AvailablePercentage).GreaterThan(0).LessThan(60).Boost(3)))
                             )));
```

or

```
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<ApplicantsWithDetailsResponse>(
        s => s
          .Query(q => q
           .Bool(p =>
                    p.Must(queryFilter => queryFilter.MatchAll())
                            .Filter(f => f.Range(r => r.Field("AvailablePercentage").GreaterThanOrEquals(60)))
                            .Boost(5)
                            .Filter(f => f.Range(r => r.Field("AvailablePercentage").GreaterThan(0).LessThan(60)))
                            .Boost(1.2)
                             )));
```

The applicant's list coming is not as per the logic. They get mixed.

Even If I try to filter to show only values greater than 60, that also does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct; it serializes to

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "boost": 1.2,
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "AvailablePercentage": {
              "gt": 0.0,
              "lt": 60.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- the boost is applied to the entire `bool` query
- the last `Filter` assigned overwrites any previous filters
- Filters are `and`ed, so all would need to be satisfied for a match

It's useful during development to be observe what JSON the client sends to Elasticsearch. There are [numerous ways that you can do this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html), and one that is useful is

```
var defaultIndex = "default-index";
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
    .DisableDirectStreaming()
    .PrettyJson()
    .OnRequestCompleted(callDetails =>
    {
        if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n" +
                $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                     $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                     $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                     $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
        }
    });

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

This will write all requests and responses out to the Console. Note that you may not want to do this in production for every request, as there is a performance overhead in buffering requests and responses in this way.

Your query should look something like

```
var response = client.Search<ApplicantsWithDetailsResponse>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(p => p
            .Must(queryFilter => queryFilter
                .MatchAll()
            )
            .Should(f => f
                .Range(r => r
                    .Field("AvailablePercentage")
                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(60)
                    .Boost(5)
                ), f => f
                .Range(r => r
                    .Field("AvailablePercentage")
                    .GreaterThan(0)
                    .LessThan(60)
                    .Boost(1.2)
                )
            )
            .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
        )
    )
);
```

Which emits the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "AvailablePercentage": {
              "boost": 5.0,
              "gte": 60.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "AvailablePercentage": {
              "boost": 1.2,
              "gt": 0.0,
              "lt": 60.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Combine range queries with `should` clauses and specify that at least one must match using `MinimumShouldMatch`. This is needed because of the presence of a `must` clause, which means that the `should` clauses act as boosting signal to documents, but a document does not have to satisfy any of the clauses to be considered a match. With `MinimumShouldMatch` set to 1, at least one of the `should` clauses has to be satisfied to be considered a match.

Since the `must` clause is a `match_all` query in this case, we could simply omit it and remove `MinimumShouldMatch`. A `should` clause without a `must` clause implies that at least one of the clauses must match.

We can also [combine queries using operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html), for brevity. The final query would look like

```
var response = client.Search<ApplicantsWithDetailsResponse>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Range(r => r
            .Field("AvailablePercentage")
            .GreaterThanOrEquals(60)
            .Boost(5)
        ) || q
        .Range(r => r
            .Field("AvailablePercentage")
            .GreaterThan(0)
            .LessThan(60)
            .Boost(1.2)
        )
    )
);
```

which emits the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "AvailablePercentage": {
              "boost": 5.0,
              "gte": 60.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "AvailablePercentage": {
              "boost": 1.2,
              "gt": 0.0,
              "lt": 60.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```